# Selenium 2.41.0 webdriver working with Java robot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have just upgraded selenium from 2.37.1 to 2.40.0 and have come across an issue.

I am using selenium webdriver to run tests in a project. A page is using a plupload that opens an uploader window, which I have been automating in my selenium with a Java robot.

Since upgrading to 2.40.0 though when it gets to the plupload the webdriver just hangs until the i manually close the upload window and then the robot will start it's commands.

This was not an issue with 2.37.1. Has anyone come across the same problem and have a fix?
Is there any other way to handle upload windows with the webdriver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do the same using following types of code:

Type 1: Using sendKeys command

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("upload"));            
upload.sendKeys("path of your file");
```

Type 2: Using Java Robot class

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("upload"));    
upload.click();   

setClipboardData("path of your file");

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(5000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: I was using type 2 you posted, except after 'upload.click()' it doesn't progress to the robot. It looks like selenium might be waiting for a response in the click function? Although this wasn't happening before updating the 2.41.0

Comment: Both are the tested code from my end for same version of selenium. Don't know why you are getting problem. Can you share your HTMLcode snippet? So can I can test the code on your HTML.